# How can I use a tracbar to change a treeview nodes sizes and how to set the nodes text and red arrow to be fit the nodes changed size?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

The treeview control code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class AdvancedTreeView : TreeView
{
    private const int TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE = 0x1100 + 44;
    private const int TVM_GETEXTENDEDSTYLE = 0x1100 + 45;
    private const int TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER = 0x0004;
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

    private Bitmap openedIcon, closedIcon;
    private List<TreeNode> rootNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

    public AdvancedTreeView()
    {
        DrawMode = TreeViewDrawMode.OwnerDrawText;
        ShowLines = false;
        AlternateBackColor = BackColor;
        ArrowColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        this.AllowDrop = true;
    }

    public Color AlternateBackColor { get; set; }
    public Color ArrowColor { get; set; }

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        SendMessage(this.Handle, TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, (IntPtr)TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER, (IntPtr)TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER);
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDrawNode(DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {
        Color backColor = (GetTopNodeIndex(e.Node) & 1) == 0 ? BackColor : AlternateBackColor;
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(backColor))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Top, ClientSize.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
        }
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, e.Bounds);
        }

        // icon
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            Image icon = GetIcon(e.Node.IsExpanded);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(icon, e.Bounds.Left - icon.Width - 3, e.Bounds.Top);
        }

        // text (due to OwnerDrawText mode, indenting of e.Bounds will be correct)
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.Node.Text, Font, e.Bounds, ForeColor);

        // indicate selection (if not by backColor):
        if ((e.State & TreeNodeStates.Selected) != 0)
            ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, e.Bounds);
    }

    protected override void OnItemDrag(ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Move the dragged node when the left mouse button is used.
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        // Copy the dragged node when the right mouse button is used.
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            DoDragDrop(e.Item, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve the client coordinates of the mouse position.
        Point targetPoint = this.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        // Select the node at the mouse position.
        this.SelectedNode = this.GetNodeAt(targetPoint);
    }

    protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Point targetPoint = PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        TreeNode targetNode = GetNodeAt(targetPoint);
        TreeNode draggedNode = (TreeNode)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode));
        if (draggedNode == null || targetNode == null || draggedNode.Level != targetNode.Level)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            TreeNode parentNode = targetNode;
            if (!draggedNode.Equals(targetNode) && targetNode != null)
            {
                bool canDrop = true;
                while (canDrop && (parentNode != null))
                {
                    canDrop = !Object.ReferenceEquals(draggedNode, parentNode);
                    parentNode = parentNode.Parent;
                }
                if (canDrop)
                {
                    TreeNode treeNode = draggedNode.Parent;
                    if (treeNode != null)
                    {
                        int index = draggedNode.Index;
                        draggedNode.Remove();
                        treeNode.Nodes.Insert(targetNode.Index, draggedNode);
                        targetNode.Remove();
                        treeNode.Nodes.Insert(index, targetNode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int draggedindex = draggedNode.Index;
                        int targetindex = targetNode.Index;
                        draggedNode.Remove();
                        targetNode.Remove();
                        this.Nodes.Insert(targetindex, draggedNode);
                        this.Nodes.Insert(draggedindex, targetNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        SelectedNode = draggedNode;
    }

    private int GetTopNodeIndex(TreeNode node)
    {
        while (node.Parent != null)
            node = node.Parent;

        return Nodes.IndexOf(node);
    }

    // Determine whether one node is a parent 
    // or ancestor of a second node.
    private bool ContainsNode(TreeNode node1, TreeNode node2)
    {
        // Check the parent node of the second node.
        if (node2.Parent == null) return false;
        if (node2.Parent.Equals(node1)) return true;

        // If the parent node is not null or equal to the first node, 
        // call the ContainsNode method recursively using the parent of 
        // the second node.
        return ContainsNode(node1, node2.Parent);
    }

    private Image GetIcon(bool nodeIsExpanded)
    {
        if (openedIcon == null)
            InitIcons();
        return nodeIsExpanded ? openedIcon : closedIcon;
    }

    private void InitIcons()
    {
        openedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        closedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(ArrowColor))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(openedIcon))
                g.FillPolygon(b, new[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(15, 0), new Point(8, 15), });
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(closedIcon))
                g.FillPolygon(b, new[] { new Point(0, 0), new Point(15, 8), new Point(0, 15), });
        }
    }
}
```

And form1 where I'm adding the nodes and using the trackbar :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Treeview_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int numberofroots = 1000;
        int childsnum = 50;
        int childsnumperlevel = 5;
        int leveldepth = 6;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AddNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ComboboxItem boxitem = new ComboboxItem();
                boxitem.Text = i.ToString();
                comboBox1.Items.Add(boxitem);
            }

            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void AddNodes()
        {
            advancedTreeView1.Nodes.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberofroots; i++)
            {
                TreeNode subnode = advancedTreeView1.Nodes.Add("New Node " + i);

                if (allRootsWithChilds.Checked || i < childsnum)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < leveldepth; j++)
                    {

                        // Add a new child node and set subnode to the new node we just added
                        subnode = subnode.Nodes.Add(subnode.Text);
                        for (int x = 0; x < childsnumperlevel; x++)
                        {
                            subnode.Nodes.Add("New Node " + x);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void allRootsWithChilds_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                AddNodes();
        }

        private void advancedTreeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = e.Node.Text;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public class ComboboxItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            advancedTreeView1.ItemHeight = 5;
            advancedTreeView1.SelectedNode.NodeFont = new Font("Arial", 5);

            // Get the font size from combobox.
            string selectedString = trackBar1.Value.ToString();//comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            int myNodeFontSize = Int32.Parse(selectedString);

            // Set the font of root node.
            advancedTreeView1.SelectedNode.NodeFont = new Font("Arial", myNodeFontSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < advancedTreeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Count; i++)
            {
                // Set the font of child nodes.
                advancedTreeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[i].NodeFont =
                  new Font("Arial", myNodeFontSize);
            }

            // Get the bounds of the tree node.
            Rectangle myRectangle = advancedTreeView1.SelectedNode.Bounds;
            int myNodeHeight = myRectangle.Height;
            if (myNodeHeight < myNodeFontSize)
            {
                myNodeHeight = myNodeFontSize;
            }
            advancedTreeView1.ItemHeight = myNodeHeight + 4;
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem is each time I'm changing the trackBar value from 1 to 2 it's taking time the treeview to redraw. I'm not sure if it's drawing the whole treeview over again or only the nodes. Maybe the problem is the OnDrawNode override method in the AdvancedTreeView control code since this method is being called all the time.

The second problem is that when the nodes are resizing getting bigger each time when moving the trackBar to a higher value the text of the nodes is keep staying the same size and not resizing with the nodes. How can I make that the text of the nodes will be resized automatic fitting the size of the nodes?

And the red arrow the icon in the AdvancedTreeView code is also not fitting the nodes sizes the arrow is getting in each node higher and higher.

Here is a screenshot of the treeview when the trackbar value is 1: Now it's all fitting :

[image: All fitting]

And this screenshot is after I moved the trackBar to the right to about the middle about value 50 :

[image: Not fitting]

Now the text is in the middle of each node but the text is still too small and not being resized with the nodes.

And the red arrow the icon in each node seems to be on the top left corner instead like in the first screenshot.

The icon/red arrow should also resize with the nodes and stay in the centre pointing the text of the nodes.

Edit :

Tried to reduce the code in the trackBar1_Scroll event to test and it sitll drawing slow when changing the trackBar values :

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the font size from combobox.
            string selectedString = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
            int myNodeFontSize = Int32.Parse(selectedString);

            // Get the bounds of the tree node.
            Rectangle myRectangle = advancedTreeView1.SelectedNode.Bounds;
            int myNodeHeight = myRectangle.Height;
            if (myNodeHeight < myNodeFontSize)
            {
                myNodeHeight = myNodeFontSize;
            }
            advancedTreeView1.ItemHeight = myNodeHeight + 4;
        }
```

Comment: You are just drawing with the control's font.  Just use one font variable.  Your code is updating the font for every node and then you ignore it.  You could eliminate that.

Comment: @LarsTech You mean in the trackBar1_Scroll event ?

Comment: @LarsTech I updated my question I tried or reduce the code in the trackBar1_Scroll event to minimum even not using new fonts and it still drawing slowly when changing the trackBar values.

Comment: Strange now the same code in my edit part at the bottom is working smooth when moving and changing the trackbar values but it wasn't smooth and was slowly 11-12 minutes ago. Very strange.

Comment: I see it's depending on this line too : advancedTreeView1.ItemHeight = myNodeHeight + 4; If I set it to 1 instead 4 it will be slowly again but when it's set to 4 it's changing smooth but then it's jumping over by 4 values each time.  So it's not really working. I just made it jumping over by 4 values each time.